# Proof for existence of an orthogonal transformation between two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim W_1 = \dim W_2$, then there exists an orthogonal transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that $T(W_1)=W_2$

I know that orthogonal transformation is length preserving transformation and i tried to play with inner product but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Start with orthogonal bases for $W_1$ and $W_2$, extend each to $V$; then map one basis to the other.

Comment: Better still, start with ortho*normal* bases.

Comment: What are $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos edited the question

Comment: @JohnHughes I started with taking ${u_1,..., u_k}$ as orthonormal basis of $W_1$ and taking ${v_1,..., v_k}$ as basis of $W_2$. Sorry I do not know what do i do next. Can I just write $T(u_i) = v_i$?